# On the factorization of prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, cyclotomic-fields, ramification

Let $\mathbb{Q(\zeta)}/\mathbb{Q}$ be a galois extension of degree $p-1$ where $\zeta=e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{p}} $ and let $G=\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q(\zeta)}/\mathbb{Q})$ be its Galois group. Suppose we have $m\mid p-1 $ and that $q$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ different from $p$. Then by Dedekind lemma, we can factorize the ideal generated by $q$ as

$$\langle q\rangle
=\mathfrak{b}_{1}^{e}......\mathfrak{b}_{r}^{e},$$

where $\mathfrak{b}_{i} $are  ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$. By ramification theory we have $rfe=p-1$ where $ f $ the is inertial degree and $e$ is the ramification index.

Can we find a prime ideal $\langle q\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ r=m$ or $e=m $? If yes how we can find it?

Comment: IIRC the only possibility for $e > 1$ is $q=p$, which you excluded (I think that's because $X^p-1$ is separable mod $q$ if $q \neq p$, but I'm not sure). Moreover, to get $r=m$, $\mathbb{F}_q[\omega_p]$ must have dimension $\frac{p-1}{m}$. But it's not hard to show that said dimension is the multiplicative order of $q$ mod $p$. So let $g$ be a generator mod $p$, use Dirichlet's theorem to find a prime $q$ congruent to $g^m$ mod $p$, and you're done.

Comment: @Mindlack which theorem of Dirichlet you mean? the idea seems good but it needs more explanation .or can you give an example to makes it clear with $p=13$ and $m=4$ ( since $m | 12$)

Comment: I meant Dirichlet’s theorem on the infiniteness of prime numbers in arithmetic progressions. With $p=13$, $m=4$: $g=2$ works so take $q=3$, as $q$ has order $3$ mod $p$. Then $f=3$, $e=1$ so $r=4$.

Comment: @Mindlack but why you worked in $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ and found $r$ and $f$ without computing its ideals factorization? if the answer is long you can give a reference for this method in some books?

Comment: Since $e=1$ you only need to know $f$ to know $r$, and $f$ is the degree of the residue field over its prime subfield. Hence why I worked over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: @Mindlack it is still unclear form me how if we find $q$ s.t $q$ congruent to $g^{m}$ mod $p$ implies that $ <q>$ has $m$ factors?

Comment: If $q$ is congruent to $g^m$ mod $p$, then the multiplicative order of $q$ mod $p$ is $(p-1)/m$. Thus, the dimension of $\mathbb{F}_q(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a $p$-th root of unity, is $(p-1)/m$. So, in the factorization of $(q)$, we have $e=1,f=(p-1)/m$. So $r=m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $q\in\Bbb{Z}$ be a prime number distinct from $p$, and let $\mathfrak{q}\subset\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$ be a prime ideal lying over $q$, and
$$\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{b}_1^{e_1}\cdots\mathfrak{b}_r^{e_r},$$
its factorization into prime ideals, and $f_i:=\dim_{\Bbb{F}_q}\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_p]/\mathfrak{b}_i$. As you already note we have $e_1=\ldots=e_r$, and $f_1=\ldots=f_r$. Then for $e=f_1$ and $f=f_1$ we have $rfe=p-1$.

Next note that the decomposition of $q$ in $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_p]/\mathfrak{b}_i$ is determined by the factorization of $\Phi_p$, the $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial, over $\Bbb{F}_q$, by the Kummer-Dedekind theorem. Of course $\Phi_p$ is separable over $\Bbb{F}_q$ because $X^p-1$ is, so $q$ does not ramify and hence $e=1$. This shows that if $m\neq1$ then we cannot find a prime $q$ such that $e=m$. If $m=1$ then *every* prime $q\neq p$ has $e=m$.

It follows that $rf=p-1$ and so we can find a prime $q$ with $r=m$ for every divisor $m$ of $p-1$ if and only if we can find a prime $q'$ with $f=m$ for every divisor $m$ of $p-1$. Of course $f$ is precisely the multiplicative order of $q'$ mod $p$, so such a prime number exists for every $m$ by Dirichlet's theorem on prime numbers in arithmetic progressions.

Comment: the only part which is unclear for me is how we can find such $q'$

Comment: why $f$ I precisely the multiplicative order of $q'$  mod $p$?

Comment: Because $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_p]/\mathfrak{b}_i$ is a field of characteristic $q$ that is generated (over $\Bbb{F}_q$) by an element of multiplicative order $p$. So it is $\Bbb{F}_{q^f}$ where $f$ is the least positive integer such that $p$ divides $q^f-1$, i.e. $f$ is the order of $q$ mod $p$.

Comment: Also, I do not know of any constructive way to find such $q'$ other than simply checking all numbers congruent to $a\pmod{p}$, where $a$ is any number of multiplicative order $m$ mod $p$. From my limited practical experience, such primes are not rare and you will find one rather quickly, for any given $p$ and $m$.